# If ( $currentCount <= $allowedCount ) .. Returns 1 extra?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

For some reason this code still returns 2 instead of one?

```
$allowedCount = 1; ( This figure is set inside the database )


$sql_count = mysql_query("SELECT usrid FROM mytable WHERE usrid=".$uid) or die(mysql_error());  
$currentCount = mysql_num_rows( $sql_count );


$currentCount = 1; ( In this example current count returns a 1 )



if ( $currentCount <= $allowedCount ) {

// do this OK

} else {

// do this Not OK

}
```

What im trying to do is check if the user has reached their limit, if so then disallow them further INSERT queries etc....

Would this be a simple approach?

Comment: Why not use `COUNT(*)` in your `SELECT`?

Comment: depending on where you get $uid from, this could be a potential sql injection vulnerability. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

check your db, you may have duplicate record. if your using a form to insert the data it may be reinserting data upon page refresh. if not check your db for duplication.

Comment: @Jared, I will try that but i think my problem is that i am saying if 1 <= 1 then allow this.. which means that they can still do it once more.

Comment: @DGM the code i posted is stripped right down for simplicity. I am definately escaping and also grabbing the usr id from a global that cant be changed.

Comment: I did think that but i have phpmyadmin opened on another monitor and have made sure that only one entry is there.